Issues with generic types and defaults when using TypeScript in strict mode
I'm currently refactoring a codebase to support TypeScript's strict mode. However, I've ran into an issue with functions that leverage generics.
In essence, I have a function that takes an object with a blocks property, this property uses a type that is generic, but has default types.
This is the definition of the object:
export type Context<
  S extends VariableSchema = VariableSchema,
  R extends VariableSchema = VariableSchema,
> = {
  blocks: { [key: string]: Block };
  schema: S;
  result: R;
};

The Block type itself is generic as well and looks like this:
export type Block<
  ParamMap extends BlockParamSchema = BlockParamSchema,
  HandleMap extends { [key: string]: string } = { [key: string]: string },
> = {
  label: string;
  parameters: ParamMap;
  validateParameters: (args: {
    parameters: ConvertVariableSchemaToObjectType<ParamMap>;
    getVariableDefinition: (name: string) => Variable;
  }) => z.AnyZodObject;
  handles: HandleMap;
  execute: (args: BlockExecutionApi<ParamMap, HandleMap>) => Promisable<void>;
};

I then use it in the following manner:
export const deductionCalculationContext = createContext({
  blocks: defaultBlocks,
  schema: {
    deductionYtd: v.number('Deduction YTD'),
    eligibleWages: v.number('Eligible Wages'),
  },
  result: {
    employeeAmount: v.number('Employee Amount'),
    companyAmount: v.number('Company Amount'),
  },
});

All Blocks are declared using a createBlock function which infers the generic types of Block for type safety. Specifically, it ensures that when a developer passes a set of parameters, the validator arguments are typed based on that:
export const conditionBlock = createBlock({
  label: 'If',

  parameters: {
    when: {
      label: 'Condition',
      type: 'unknown',
      required: true,
    },
    equalTo: {
      label: 'Equal to',
      type: 'unknown',
      required: true,
    },
  },

  handles: {
    true: 'True',
    false: 'False',
  },

  execute: async ({ parameters, fireHandle }) => {
    parameters.when === parameters.equalTo ? fireHandle('true') : fireHandle('false');
  },
});

However even though it's the same type, less the generic args, TS won't compile. You can find a reproduction of this issue here.
TypeScript Playground Reproduction
You can see the error on line 173.
I've tried the following things:

Omitting the blocks and redeclaring it without generics works, but I'm afraid of the type safety issues it'll bring.

Disabling strictFunctionTypes also works, but breaks other type safety features related to functions.

Making the blocks property generic.

Making the blocks property generic, but without a generic type constraint, and then using a mapped type, conditional types, and inference to get the values of the generics. This worked in concept but I can't apply it since it'd reference the type recursively.


I'm trying to avoid having to explicitly pass the generic type, and I know there are libraries out there that have accomplished this.

Please [edit] to provide a plaintext [mre]. What's VariableSchema (and anything else you didn't declare)? And screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions..  Ideally we should be able to copy and paste your code into our own IDEs and see the issue you're having without other unrelated issues getting in the way.  Right now it's not straightforward to get started on it.

Hello, I've created a TS Playground reproducible example. Thank you.

Thanks. Do note that you need the code to be here, as plain text. Not just as a link to the playground (although that link is a nice supplement). Also, 173 lines is almost certainly not minimal; have you tried to reduce that example down to the smallest version that demonstrates the issue? In my experience on SO, virtually every question I've dealt with has had a reproducible example that fits on a single screen at once. Any example that requires scrolling up and down a bunch to see what's happening is probably too big.

Given how big this example is, I'd say use blocks: { [key: string]: Block<any, any> } in Context and move on. Anything more complicated and "safe" than that will need a stripped-down version of this code to demonstrate in a reasonable amount of time and space. How would you like to proceed?
